# realizar calculo al presionar TAB

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy seleccionando 2 inputs para calcular un valor entre hora usando el `keypress`. Mi consulta es como puedo realizar el calculo solamente al presionar la tecla `TAB`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#horaInicio').timepicker({
    'scrollDefault': 'now',
    'timeFormat': 'G:i'
});

$('#horaTermino').timepicker({
    'scrollDefault': 'now',
    'timeFormat': 'G:i'
});

$("#horaTermino").keypress(function(event) {
    ObtieneTotHoras();

})

});

function ObtieneTotHoras() {
  var contar = 0;
  HDesde = $('#horaInicio').val();
  HHasta = $('#horaTermino').val();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="" id="horaInicio" value=""> <br>
<input type="text" name="" id="horaTermino" value="">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/timepicker@1.11.12/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola MoteCl. Veo que tienes el evento `keypress`. ¿que has probado para que solo salga con la tecla Tab? Que errores concretos tuviste? (igual [esta pagina](http://keycode.info/) te da una pista)  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info en como mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Funciona bien si presiono el TAB pero tambien si presiono ENTER O Cualquier tecla. Quiero llamar a la funcion solamente si presiono la tecla `TAB`

Comment: Si, y qué has probado para que solo salga con la tecla tab?  en mi comentario anterior te indico la pagina  http://keycode.info/ que te muestra los codigo de cada tecla para que puedas comprobar que se ha pulsado la que quieres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer. Pero especificamente al presionar tab pierder el foco si estas parado en input.

Podria aprovechar esto y realizar el calculo al perder el foco de ese input. Si quieres ya obligatoriamente hacerlo con una tecla.

Podrias obtener el key Ascii de la letra y en un If validarlo con el valor Ascci de la tecla tab que es 9

```
$("#horaTermino").keypress(function(event) {
   if(event.keyCode==9)
   // ObtieneTotHoras();

})
```

Comment: Hola Gustavo, bienvenido a e[es.so]. Gracias por responder y aportar pero es mejor esperar a que el autor edite la pregunta y explique qué intentó y qué fue mal. Hasta ahora solo pide sin mostrar lo que ha probado. Aqui buscamos ayudar sobre un trabajo previo de investigacion y pruebas, no sobre una tarea que necesitan hacer. Un saludo

Comment: Hola gracias por la Bienvenida. Espero seguir colaborando y entiendo lo que mencionas

Comment: Gracias el `event.keyCode==9` Funciono muy bien